# ADC12 MSP430 frequency 500 KHz

Tags: uart, msp430, adc

How can I configure an ADC to 500 KHz. It's impossible to use "ADC12_A_CLOCKDIVIDER_10" instead of "ADC12_A_CLOCKDIVIDER_5". What can I do?

ADC12_A_init(ADC12_A_BASE,
ADC12_A_SAMPLEHOLDSOURCE_SC,
ADC12_A_CLOCKSOURCE_ADC12OSC,
ADC12_A_CLOCKDIVIDER_5);

Thanks a lot ;).